# Minimizing the amount of code

Tags: python, django

I have this function below and I need to also check if each of these variables are none before translating.

```
def save(self):
    # add an an if condition to check all the below variables if they are none
    # if self.name_es or ..... is not None:
    self.name_es = translateField(self.name, 'es') if not None
    self.name_ar = translateField(self.name, 'ar')
    self.description_es = translateField(self.description, 'es')
    self.description_ar = translateField(self.description, 'ar')
    super(City, self).save()
```

This is the translate function:

```
def translateField(text, lang):
    try:
        return client.translate(text, lang)
    except:
        pass
```

The problem is that I have the above in like many classes in my Model. In each save function I'm doing the same for different variables.

What can I do over here to minimize the amount of code? The '_es' and '_ar' are always appended to these variables that I need to return the output of the translation.

Comment: If what is not `None`? `self.name`? or `self.name_es`?

Comment: If an error is raised in `translateField`, that function returns `None`.  Is this your intent?

Answer (score 0):

Use `setattr`:

```
for lang in ["es", "ar"]:
    setattr(self, "name_" + lang, translateField(self.name, lang))
    setattr(self, "description_" + lang, translateField(self.description, 'es'))
```

If you have lots of fields as well as lots of languages, then you can even make this a nested loop.

And may I warn against [bare `except` clauses](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#programming-recommendations)?

Comment: That makes little sense; Why would that function look for attributes in your class?

Comment: I meant the following:
`def translateField(fieldName)`, where `fieldName` is `self.name`, then it loops over both languages strings in the array, use `setattr` to do as @larsmans did and I'll check per loop if `self.name_es` for example is none... and so on. I don't want to look for both translation fields in each class.

Comment: @MohdIsmail: you need to pass `self` as well for `setattr`, so that would make `translateField` a method of your class.

Comment: @MohdIsmail: I understand, but if you're going to do the `setattr` inside it, then it should be a method.